# Rails - How to FIND record having FIELD which LIKE a given string MOST

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I have already inserted a lot of data into my database in past via Admin console using `active admin` gem.

However, for now my client wants me to update data from his `google sheet` file. In this file, there are some data that has already been inserted before but the inserted record data does not 100% match the sheet file. ( but the sheet data matches the database 80%-90% and there's no 2 cells in the Sheet file have data with that match )

For pseudo code

```
Question.order('title LIKE MOST ?', "%#{Sheet_cell_data}%").first.update_attributes(title: "%#{Sheet_cell_data}%")
```

Is there a way to solve my problem. In my knowledge I only know `LIKE` but it doesn't seem to be the solution.

Answer (score -1):

As I know, you should use Elasticsearch, and that is what I am using.

In addition, there is Gem for Elasticsearch, searchkick. https://github.com/ankane/searchkick